# How to make a groupped linq Query like a flat table

Tags: linq

Hi
i want to create a query for a table that is like this:
1.i have a multiple question and i want to count the number of each response to every answer to multiplequestion result and show them in a query that is formated like this:
1.ID  2.qestion phrase 3.q1 4.q2 5.q3 6.q4 7.count1 8.count2 9.count3 10.count4 
i have created a linq query like this that is from answers table and after that i can join these with the ID to questions table and get the phrase and other:

```
var q4 = (from x in LinqDB.PTAs
             where x.PTID == int.Parse(DropDownListPeriodID.SelectedValue) &&
                   x.PTUser.PTUserID >= ID1 && x.PTUser.PTUserID <= ID2 
             group x by x.PTQID into GRPA //& x.PTAID
             select new {
                 GRPA.Key,
                 A1=(
                     from f in GRPA
                     group f by f.Answer into FG
                     select FG.Count()
                    )});
```

but it gives a second layer that i don't want becouse of the format
 i tried this:

```
var Q = from x in LinqDB.PTAs
            where x.PTID == int.Parse(DropDownListPeriodID.SelectedValue) &&
                  x.PTUser.PTUserID >= ID1 && x.PTUser.PTUserID <= ID2 
            group x by new { x.PTQID, x.Answer } into gr
            select new {gr.Key.PTQID,gr.Key.Answer,A1=gr.Count() };
```

so any suggestions to this or maybe changing the second query in a post processing so it can be like my format?
Thx for your Answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //process user input before going into the database.
int selectedID = int.Parse(DropDownListPeriodID.SelectedValue);

  //go to the database and get the data.
List<PTA> records =
(
  from x in LinqDB.PTAs
  where x.PTID == selectedID
    && ID1 <= x.PTUser.PTUserID && x.PTUser.PTUserID <= ID2
  select x
).ToList();

 // group up the data for presentation.    
var questions =
  from x in records
  group x by new {x.PTQID, x.Answer} into g1
  group g1 by g1.Key.PTQID into g2
  select new
  {
    PTQID = g2.Key,
    Answers =
       from y in g2
       select new
       {
         Answer = y.Key.Answer,
         AnswerCount = y.Count()
       }
  };
```

---

```
    // group up the data for presentation.
   var questions =
   from x in records
   group x by x.PTQID into g
   let answers = g.GroupBy(y => y.Answer)
   let answer1 = answers.First()
   let answer2 = answers.Skip(1).First()
   let answer3 = answers.Skip(2).First()
   let answer4 = answers.Skip(3).First()
   select new
   {
     PTQID = g.Key,
     Answer1 = answer1.Key,
     Answer1Count = answer1.Count(),
     Answer2 = answer1.Key,
     Answer2Count = answer1.Count(),
     Answer3 = answer1.Key,
     Answer3Count = answer1.Count(),
     Answer4 = answer1.Key,
     Answer4Count = answer1.Count(),
   };
```

Comment: Hello David B Thanks for your response. but the query you send gives 3 layers not 1.i said it that i want it to be like that format coz i want to send this in a crystal reports source and it doesn't recognize more than 1 layer.i uploaded the images of first query that is in 2 layers and the the second query that is 1 layer.

Comment: http://imgbot.com/images/59318563781857354819.jpg http://imgbot.com/images/71394487961413797036.jpg

Comment: it sould be like the second alone image that everything is in one flat table like results .so it should just give one RESULT VIEW in debugging mode and no more.again thx very much .